# Why is a fitted value missing?

Tags: r

I want to calculate the predicted values of Enep and PR on the variable stfdem. In order to do this I run a regression but I somehow only get 24 predicted values.

Enep and PR are 25 different variables (no NA`s) for the 25 countries that I am observing and stfdem (y) stems from a dataset with 45k observations (on the same 25 countries).
The same summary process has worked with another set of variables. I think, therefore, something is off with the original dataset.
Please find my code and the dataset with Enep and PR below (which I have also integrated into my main dataset, ESS_subset).

Do you know what I miss here?

Code:

```
mod_swd_elec <- lm (stfdem~Enep+PR, data = ESS_subset)
summary(mod_swd_elec)

fitted.values.elec <- as.data.frame(predict(mod_swd_elec))
fitted.values.elec <- as.data.frame(unique(fitted.values.elec[,1]))
```

Data:

```
   cntry  Enep PR
1     BE 10.04  1
2     BG   4.4  1
3     CH  6.35  1
4     CY   3.9  1
5     CZ  6.75  1
6     DE  5.58  1
7     DK  5.72  1
8     EE  4.73  1
9     ES  2.79  1
10    FI  6.46  1
11    FR  4.32  0
12    GB  3.71  0
13    HU  2.82  1
14    IE  4.43  1
15    IL  7.37  1
16    IS  4.55  1
17    IT  3.82  1
18    LT   8.9  1
19    NL  6.97  1
20    NO  4.56  1
21    PO  3.72  1
22    PT  3.96  1
23    SE  4.78  1
24    SI  5.47  1
25    SK  5.53  1
```

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from `stfdem`, but it is not provided. Can you please provide `ESS_subset`?

Comment: How could I do that in a sensible way as the dataset has 47000+ observations?

Comment: [What is the best way to add your dataset to a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250975/10488504)

Comment: Perhaps, by chance, you have two identical fitted values, and the `unique` statement in your final line is removing one of them.